# View your rated music, apps and etc. on the iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, mac

I would like to ask, where could I find all my rated music, apps and etc. on the iTunes? Moreover, how could I unrate those items?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Arthur

Answer (score 1):

Follow these simple steps to remove a review that you have written:

1. Sign in to the iTunes Store.
2. From the Store menu, choose “View My Account” (or click “Account” in the “Quick Links” menu on the right).
3. In the Settings section, click “Manage” next to “Reviews and Ratings”.

   [image]

   You’ll end up on this page:

   [image]
4. Click “Remove” next to the review or rating you would like to remove.

Note: The review that you remove will not immediately disappear. Once removed, the text from the review will no longer be visible but may be retained in Apple’s systems indefinitely.

[**Source:** Apple’s Knowledge Base](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5024)

Comment: There is no such thing as "Reviews and Ratings."

Comment: @Arthur Yes there is. I’m there right now: http://i.imgur.com/texRr.png

Comment: I cannot find it anywhere... Maybe it depends on the store (I am using the UK store)?

Comment: @Arthur Just edited my answer, adding an alternative way of reaching the “Account” page (via the Quick Links menu). Once you get to the account page, scroll all the way down, and you’ll see the Settings section as in my screenshot.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CtPJw.jpg

Comment: @Arthur That’s weird. It appears you never left a review or a rating using that account…

Comment: Hmmmm... Actually, I had put some stars on some of the items.